# What is the difference between population transfer between two quantum states/system and the state transfer in a quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In  lambda type atomic system, the population is transferred from one stable ground state to another by using counter intuitive sequence of pulses. This process is well known as stimulated Raman adiabatic passage (STIRAP). However in optomechanics the coherent superposition of states are observed between mechanical mode and cavity mode. In the above cases population is transferred from either one state to another or from mechanical to cavity mode and vice versa.

How can I understand the difference between state exchange /transfer and population transfer between two physical system /states of a quantum system?